# Error implementing the Thrift API

Tags: java, exception, implementation, thrift

I'm implementing the Thrift Remote Procedure call framework in Java. I set up thrift and generated my skeleton code without a lot of issues, but now that I'm actually using the API methods, I get strange errors.

Here are the errors I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot write to null outputStream
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:142)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:163)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:91)
at SimonSays$Client.send_registerClient(SimonSays.java:102)
at SimonSays$Client.registerClient(SimonSays.java:96)
at simon.main(testClass.java:16)
```

I don't think I'm not making any mistakes, but just to make sure, here's the code that's leading to the errors:

```
TProtocol prot = new TBinaryProtocol(new TSocket("http://thriftpuzzle.facebook.com",9030));
    SimonSays.Client client = new SimonSays.Client(prot);

    client.registerClient("userEmailAddress@gmail.com");
```

The error is said to be generated from the `client.registerClient()` call, but that is a call to the code generated by Thrift, which makes me feel that I'm doing something wrong in setting up the connection itself.

The part about making a `TProtocol` instance I included myself, and it's likely that that's where the problem lies.

I was hoping that someone would have more of an idea about what's going wrong that I do.

Please let me know if more information or clarification is needed.

Edit: I found the `TProtocol` instantiation statement from the [Cassandra Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples03)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `open()` method on your `TSocket` instance in order for it to connect and obtain the input/output streams it needs.

Source: [TSocket.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#NPWGicy0Ryg/trunk/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TSocket.java)